# Robot Framework headless mode is ignore CA certificate installed and giving loging promt

Tags: selenium-webdriver, robotframework, headless, google-chrome-headless

I am trying to automate a Service Now related basic test case using Robot Framework. In the non-headless mode, opening SNOW is directly giving me the home page, but in headless mode its giving me the login prompt to enter user name.
Hence, how can i make headless mode to work as same as non-headless (normal mode)?

Code I tried:

```
*** Settings ***
Library    SeleniumLibrary

*** Test Cases ***
Chrome
    Open Browser    service-now-url     headlesschrome
    Capture Page Screenshot
    Close Browser
```

This gives this output-
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QyJtl.png

This code is working fine and using installed CA cert for loging.

```
*** Settings ***
Library    SeleniumLibrary

*** Test Cases ***
Chrome
    Open Browser    service-now-url     chrome
    Capture Page Screenshot
    Close Browser
```

Answer (score 0):

In headless mode, the browser does not display a graphical user interface, which is why you're seeing the login prompt instead of the home page. To make headless mode work the same as non-headless mode, you can try the following steps:

1. Provide the login credentials programmatically: Since the login
   prompt is displayed in headless mode, you can provide the username
   and password directly in your test case code.

Here's an example:

```
*** Settings ***
Library    SeleniumLibrary

*** Test Cases ***
Chrome
    Open Browser    service-now-url     headlesschrome
    Input Text    ${username_locator}    your_username
    Input Password    ${password_locator}    your_password
    Submit Form
    Capture Page Screenshot
    Close Browser
```

2. Use a browser profile with saved login credentials: Another option is to use a browser profile that already has the login credentials saved. This way, when the browser opens in headless mode, it can automatically log in using the saved credentials.

Here's an example using ChromeOptions:

```
*** Settings ***
Library    SeleniumLibrary

*** Test Cases ***
Chrome
    ${options}=    Evaluate    sys.modules['selenium.webdriver'].ChromeOptions()    sys, selenium.webdriver
    ${profile_path}=    Evaluate    os.path.expanduser('~/.config/google-chrome/Default')    os
    Call Method    ${options}    add_argument    --headless
    Call Method    ${options}    add_argument    --user-data-dir=${profile_path}
    Create Webdriver    Chrome    chrome_options=${options}
    Go To    service-now-url
    Capture Page Screenshot
    Close Browser
```

Note: The profile path (~/.config/google-chrome/Default) is specific to Chrome on Linux. You may need to modify it according to your operating system.